# Thymeleaf View not recognizing the specified action view

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am facing an issue with viewresolver. Thymeleaf viewresolver not picking up the specified view in my controller action method and it is taking action name as view path instead.

Below is my thymeleaf configuration and controller code.

Controller :

```
@ModelAttribute("user")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/register")
public String register(Model model, @Valid User user, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, final Locale locale) {if (result.hasErrors()) {
        List<ObjectError> errors = result.getAllErrors();
        for (ObjectError error : errors) {
            log.error("Errors are :: " + error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        return "registration/indexed";
    }else{------my operations------return "profile/index"}}
```

thymeleaf config..

```
<!-- THYMELEAF: Template Resolver for email templates -->
<bean id="emailTemplateResolver"
    class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="mail/" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="order" value="2" />
    <!-- Template cache is true by default. Set to false if you want -->
    <!-- templates to be automatically updated when modified. -->
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- Thymeleaf template resolver -->
<bean id="webTemplateResolver"
    class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

<!-- THYMELEAF: Template Engine (Spring3-specific version) -->
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolvers">
        <set>
            <ref bean="emailTemplateResolver" />
            <ref bean="webTemplateResolver" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="thymeleafViewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

But my Thymeleaf not recognizing "registration/index" and it is searching for "registration/register"

Would anybody please suggest what I have to do??

Thanks & Regards,

Gupta Katakam

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out the problem. The problem is due to @ModelAttribute("user") . When I removed this line on top of my action method the problem got resolved.

Thanks & Regards,

Gupta Katakam